# How to used add_widget on a BoxLayout created on kvlang with kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy

I need to add a widget by python code on my kvlang created Screen. But, when I try to add it, it return that my BoxLayout doesn't exist.

I think this is happening because the .py code is started before the kvlang, because when I use `on_enter: print('a')` it returns the error and don't print `a`.

How can I do this?

**.py code**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Screen1(Screen):

    def __init__(self):

        bt = Button()
        bt.text = 'def'
        self.bx.add_widget(bt)

class rootApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Screen1()

rootApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
<Screen1>:

    BoxLayout:
        id:bx
        Button:
            text:'abc'
```

Comment: I think you need `self.ids.bx.add_widget(bt)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ids` to access `bx`. You will also need to call the `__init__()` method of the super class. Like this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Screen1(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bt = Button()
        bt.text = 'def'
        self.ids.bx.add_widget(bt)

class rootApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen1()

rootApp().run()
```

Comment: Worked! Do you know if there's a way to select the position that the button is going to be added? Like, I have a boxlayout with `[label','label']`, and I wan't to place a button in the middle of the labels, getting `[label','button','label']`

Comment: You can add an `index` to the `add_widget()` like `add_widget(widget, index=1)`.